# Bring Phonegap App to the Foreground

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing a HTML5 phonegap app (which will be installed on both Andriod and iOS) and wondering how can I bring my app to the foreground once the user switched to another app?

For example, there is a new notification coming from the server and I want to activate my app and bring it to foreground for user attention (much like when someone calls you on Viber, your screen splashes with the "ringing" screen)?

[image: Viber Incoming Call]

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: In iOS you can't bring your app to the foreground programmatically. It's at the user's discretion.